# Images are not showing only in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

This is a high-level question so some general guidance will be helpful here.

I am developing an app using react native and firebase. I have a web version, and am developing a react native app and testing it using iOS simulator.

From yesterday, iOS simulator won't show any image for my app, while the images all show up properly on my web/mobile web versions.

Any potential reasons why this might be happening? New to app development and am very confused, especially because until yesterday all the images were loaded on iOS simulator as well without any problem.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Any network errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the simulator iOS 14 and your RN version is below 63? if yes this is a known issue you can use a patch package in RN issues in GitHub that fixes this or use `react-native-fast-image`. I personally use fastImage because it has a lot of benefits.